# wordpress value multiplied by 2 SQL query UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to increment a value of my db on wordpress but I have a strange problem that if I want to add +2 to my value, it will add +4, and if I put 50 it will be 100 etc... And on the internet I have not found my problem at all. Do you have any idea where this problem comes from ?

Here is my line of code :

```php
$wpdb->exec("UPDATE wp_users SET teacher_money = teacher_money + 2 WHERE ID = 2");
```

I have the same problem when creating my own `$db object`

On my db my `teacher_money` column is of type `float`.

Thanks !

Comment: I'd guess that you're simply running the query twice, probably as a result of requesting the page twice.

Comment: Agree with Alex. I'd wager you are maybe redirecting after the calculation runs. Maybe your query occurs before the check for www, or before the page id is converted into a slug.

Comment: What is wpdb::exec ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is speculative, but your obsersations imply that you are actually executing the following query:

```sql
UPDATE wp_users SET teacher_money = teacher_money * 2 WHERE ID = 2;
```

That is, the update query actually being run is *multiplying* the teacher's money by 2, rather than adding 2.